# Custom property event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dispatchevent

I intercept all the click events in my iframe with this code:

```
$(doc.body).on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.from === undefined) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        interceptEvent(e);
    }
}
```

The `interceptEvent(e)` sends an XML message (with the path to the original e.target)
The message is caught (on another browser) by the function:

```
if (document.createEvent) { //Netscape
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(value, false, true);
    evt.from = 'trigger'; //trigger for recognize a XML programmatically event
    return !$('.browser').contents().find(path)[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

The objective of this function is to replicate the event.
To avoid loops (interception is active on other browsers too) I add to `dispatchedEvent` a the property "from".

Despite this the `e.form` is always `undefined`, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you use jQuery, right?

the jQuery event does not have a property **from** and only normalizes the following event properties:

- target
- relatedTarget
- pageX
- pageY
- which
- metaKey

if you want to pass custom properties with the event you need to trigger your custom event with jQuery itself. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ or access the original Event with `event.originalEvent`